# Unicode: How to integrate Jansson(JSON library) with ICU special UTF-8 data types?

Tags: c, json, unicode, utf-8, icu

I've been developing a C application that expects wide range of UTF-8 characters, so I started using [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) library to support Unicode characters, but it seems things aren't working nicely with other libraries(mainly, jansson, a JSON library).

Even though [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) claims it fully supports UTF-8, it only expects chars as parameters(IIRC, a single byte isn't enough for Unicode chars), while ICU uses a special type called `UChar`(16byte sized character, at least on my system).

Casting a Unicode character to a regular character doesn't seem like a solution to me, since casting bigger data to smaller ones will cause data lose. I tried casting anyway; it didn't work.

So my question would be: How can I make the two libraries work nicely together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get ICU to produce output in UTF-8 using `toUTF8`/[`toUTF8String`](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#a05777d826515a20a0b2bb8f4108f9348). (toUTF8String gives you a `std::string` so `.c_str()` to get the `char*` that Jansson wants.

Comment: Just a note: As for C API, it's `u_strToUTF8` instead of `toUTF8String`